# Custom validation messages pop up even when input is valid

Tags: html, validation

I am trying to define my own invalidate error message for input `type='email'`.

I use the below HTML. The problem is that when submitting the input, I get the custom error message EVEN if the input value is a valid.

```
<input name="resp_mail" required="required" onchange="try{setCustomValidity(' ')}catch(e){}" onkeypress="try{setCustomValidity(' ')}catch(e){}" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Custom error message')" type="email" placeholder="Enter mail" />
```

Also see [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Claudius/wjr1y1tf/13/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you change the order to have the oninvalid first and remove the space for onchange and onkeypress it seem to me that it works.

```
<input 
  name="resp_mail"
  required="required" 
  oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Custom error message')" 
  onchange="try{setCustomValidity('')}catch(e){}" 
  onkeypress="try{setCustomValidity('')}catch(e){}" 
  type="email" 
  placeholder="Enter mail"
/>
```

Comment: Very strange but - thanks seem to work. Wonder if this behaviour is a bug or documented?

Comment: Don't know. It looked right to me, so I just tried different combinations :))

Answer (score 0):

this is how you should do it

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (e) {

  /** @this {HTMLInputElement}*/
  function validateInput () {
      const label = document.getElementById("label-"+this.id);
    if (this.validity.patternMismatch) {
        this.setCustomValidity("If pattern does not match set this message");
        
        return;
    }
    if (this.validity.badInput) {
        this.setCustomValidity("if badInput is invalid show this message");
        
        return;
    }
    
    if (this.validity.patternMismatch) {
        this.setCustomValidity("if patternMismatch is invalid show this message");
        
        return;
    }
    if (this.validity.rangeOverflow) {
        this.setCustomValidity("if rangeOverflow is invalid show this message");
        
        return;
    }
    if (this.validity.rangeUnderflow) {
        this.setCustomValidity("if rangeUnderflow is invalid show this message");
        
        return;
    }
    if (this.validity.stepMismatch) {
        this.setCustomValidity("if stepMismatch is invalid show this message");
        
        return;
    }
    if (this.validity.tooLong) {
        this.setCustomValidity("if tooLong is invalid show this message");
        
        return;
    }
    if (this.validity.tooShort) {
        this.setCustomValidity("if tooShort is invalid show this message");
        
        return;
    }
    if (this.validity.typeMismatch) {
        this.setCustomValidity("if typeMismatch is invalid show this message");
        
        return;
    }
    
    if (this.validity.valueMissing) {
        this.setCustomValidity("if valueMissing is invalid show this message");
        
        return;
    }
    // IF YOW INPUT IS VALID CLEANUP CUSTOMMESSAGE
    if (this.validity.valid) {
        this.setCustomValidity("");
        
        return;
    }
  }

  const phone = document.getElementById("phone");

  phone?.addEventListener("blur", function (evt){
      validateInput.call(this);
  });


  validateInput.call(phone);

});
```

```css
label,button {
display: block}

input {
margin-bottom: .5rem;
}
```

```html
<form>
<label id="phone-label" for="phone">Phone</label>
<input maxlength="14" minlength="14" enterkeyhint="send" inputmode="tel" required="true" name="phone" id="phone" type="tel" pattern="[\(]\d{3}[\)]\s\d{3}-\d{4}" />
<button type="submit">submit</button>
```